# F1-F12 Mnemonic Java

Tags: java, keyevent, jmenuitem, jmenubar, mnemonics

So I've been working on setting up a really basic menu for Java with a couple of different ways to select MenuItems, and I came across a weird situation. If I try to use the <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> keys with a KeyListener and KeyEvent, it reads alternate keys according to the last letters in the alphabet. Specifically it goes:

F1 = P F2 = Q F3 = R F4 = S F1 = T F6 = U F7 = V F8 = W F9 = X F10 = Y F11 = Z

I haven't been able to figure out what triggers what is supposed to be the F12 function.

In my code I use the `KeyEvent.VK_Fnum` method when creating the `JMenuItems`, so I'm really not sure what's up. If there's some odd rule that's keeping me from directly using <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> I haven't found it for Java, so any help is appreciated.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.event.MenuEvent;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MathGameMenuBar implements ActionListener, KeyListener{
    public String fileName1;
    public String fileName2;
    public String fileName3;

    public MathGameMenuBar(){
        fileName1 = "Image1.jpg";
        fileName2 = "Image2.jpg";
        fileName3 = "Image3.jpg";
    }

    public JMenuBar MenuBarCreator(){


        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();



        JMenu ImageMenu = new JMenu("Image");
        JMenu ProblemNumMenu = new JMenu("Problem #");
        JMenu NumSelectMenu = new JMenu("Base Number Select");

        JMenu ImageSubMenu = new JMenu("Image List");


        JMenuItem Image1 = new JMenuItem("Image 1", KeyEvent.VK_F1);
        JMenuItem Image2 = new JMenuItem("Image 2", KeyEvent.VK_F2);
        JMenuItem Image3 = new JMenuItem("Image 3", KeyEvent.VK_F3);

        JMenuItem Split4 = new JMenuItem("4 Problems", KeyEvent.VK_F1);
        JMenuItem Split9 = new JMenuItem("9 Problems", KeyEvent.VK_F2);
        JMenuItem Split16 = new JMenuItem("16 Problems", KeyEvent.VK_F3);

        JMenuItem Select1  = new JMenuItem("1", KeyEvent.VK_F1);
        JMenuItem Select2  = new JMenuItem("2", KeyEvent.VK_F2);
        JMenuItem Select3  = new JMenuItem("3", KeyEvent.VK_F3);
        JMenuItem Select4  = new JMenuItem("4", KeyEvent.VK_F4);
        JMenuItem Select5  = new JMenuItem("5", KeyEvent.VK_F5);
        JMenuItem Select6  = new JMenuItem("6", KeyEvent.VK_F6);
        JMenuItem Select7  = new JMenuItem("7", KeyEvent.VK_F7);
        JMenuItem Select8  = new JMenuItem("8", KeyEvent.VK_F8);
        JMenuItem Select9  = new JMenuItem("9", KeyEvent.VK_F9);
        JMenuItem Select10  = new JMenuItem("10", KeyEvent.VK_F10);
        JMenuItem Select11 = new JMenuItem("11", KeyEvent.VK_F11);
        JMenuItem Select12  = new JMenuItem("12", KeyEvent.VK_F12);



        Image1.addActionListener(this);
        Image1.setActionCommand("i1");
        Image2.addActionListener(this);
        Image2.setActionCommand("i2");
        Image3.addActionListener(this);
        Image3.setActionCommand("i3");

        Split4.addActionListener(this);
        Split4.setActionCommand("s4");
        Split9.addActionListener(this);
        Split9.setActionCommand("s9");
        Split16.addActionListener(this);
        Split16.setActionCommand("s16");

        Select1.addActionListener(this);
        Select1.setActionCommand("sl1");
        Select2.addActionListener(this);
        Select2.setActionCommand("sl2");
        Select3.addActionListener(this);
        Select3.setActionCommand("sl3");
        Select4.addActionListener(this);
        Select4.setActionCommand("sl4");
        Select5.addActionListener(this);
        Select5.setActionCommand("sl5");
        Select6.addActionListener(this);
        Select6.setActionCommand("sl6");
        Select7.addActionListener(this);
        Select7.setActionCommand("sl7");
        Select8.addActionListener(this);
        Select8.setActionCommand("sl8");
        Select9.addActionListener(this);
        Select9.setActionCommand("sl9");
        Select10.addActionListener(this);
        Select10.setActionCommand("sl10");
        Select11.addActionListener(this);
        Select11.setActionCommand("sl11");
        Select12.addActionListener(this);
        Select12.setActionCommand("sl12");



        menuBar.add(ImageMenu);
        menuBar.add(ProblemNumMenu);
        menuBar.add(NumSelectMenu);

        ImageMenu.add(ImageSubMenu);

        ImageSubMenu.add(Image1);
        ImageSubMenu.add(Image2);
        ImageSubMenu.add(Image3);

        ProblemNumMenu.add(Split4);
        ProblemNumMenu.add(Split9);
        ProblemNumMenu.add(Split16);

        NumSelectMenu.add(Select1);
        NumSelectMenu.add(Select2);
        NumSelectMenu.add(Select3);
        NumSelectMenu.add(Select4);
        NumSelectMenu.add(Select5);
        NumSelectMenu.add(Select6);
        NumSelectMenu.add(Select7);
        NumSelectMenu.add(Select8);
        NumSelectMenu.add(Select9);
        NumSelectMenu.add(Select10);
        NumSelectMenu.add(Select11);
        NumSelectMenu.add(Select12);



        return menuBar;
    }





    private int returnNum(int num){
        return num;
    }


    private String getFileName1(){
        return fileName1;
    }
    private String getFileName2(){
        return fileName2;
    }
    private String getFileName3(){
        return fileName3;
    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if ("i1".equals(e.getActionCommand())){
            getFileName1();
            System.out.println("yupI1");
        }
        if ("i2".equals(e.getActionCommand())){
            getFileName2();
            System.out.println("yupI2");
        }
        if ("i3".equals(e.getActionCommand())){
            getFileName3();
            System.out.println("yupI3");
        }



        if ("s4".equals(e.getActionCommand())){
            returnNum(4);
            System.out.println("yupS4");
        }
        if ("s9".equals(e.getActionCommand())){
            returnNum(9);
            System.out.println("yupS9");
        }
        if ("s16".equals(e.getActionCommand())){
            returnNum(16);
            System.out.println("yupS16");
        }



        if ("sl1".equals(e.getActionCommand())){
            returnNum(1);
            System.out.println("yup1");
        }
        if ("sl2".equals(e.getActionCommand())){
            returnNum(2);
            System.out.println("yup2");
        }
        if ("sl3".equals(e.getActionCommand())){
            returnNum(3);
            System.out.println("yup3");
        }
        if ("sl4".equals(e.getActionCommand())){
            returnNum(4);
            System.out.println("yup4");
        }
        if ("sl5".equals(e.getActionCommand())){
            returnNum(5);
            System.out.println("yup5");
        }
        if ("sl6".equals(e.getActionCommand())){
            returnNum(6);
            System.out.println("yup6");
        }
        if ("sl7".equals(e.getActionCommand())){
            returnNum(7);
            System.out.println("yup7");
        }
        if ("sl8".equals(e.getActionCommand())){
            returnNum(8);
            System.out.println("yup8");
        }
        if ("sl9".equals(e.getActionCommand())){
            returnNum(9);
            System.out.println("yup9");
        }
        if ("sl10".equals(e.getActionCommand())){
            returnNum(10);
            System.out.println("yup10");
        }
        if ("sl11".equals(e.getActionCommand())){
            returnNum(11);
            System.out.println("yup11");
        }
        if ("sl12".equals(e.getActionCommand())){
            returnNum(12);
            System.out.println("yup12");
        }
    }



    public void main(String[] args){
        MathGameMenuBar menuBar = new MathGameMenuBar();
        menuBar.MenuBarCreator();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve] before posting code (in the above case, focus on the "minimal" - you don't need to post all this code to highlight your problem)

Comment: Please read [ask].

Comment: Also, what keyboard do you have? Are the function keys enabled?